# Using find with -exec {}, is there a way to count the total?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find

I am using a command similar to this one:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Although, I am not using chmod, I am using a different command which I will not list here. This command is working fine. However, there are thousands of files and directories to be operated on, and this operation takes some time. I am wondering if there is a way to display some sort of total when the operation is complete? Perhaps a count of modified files?

The only thing I can think of is simply to do something like:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec chmod 755; echo "+"; {} \;
```

Will that work? At least we can see that something is happening... Anyone have  a better suggestion?

Comment: To help others out that may have issues with file names and spaces. You can wrap quotes around {} in order to resolve process the files/directories.

    find . -name "*.php" -exec chmod 640 "{}" \;

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This works:

```
$ find . -name "*.php" -exec chmod 755 {} \; -exec /bin/echo {} \; | wc -l
```

You have to include a second `-exec /bin/echo` for this to work. If the `find` command has no output, then `wc` has no input to count lines for.

Comment: This is what I used. Works perfectly for me. Here is my final command... it also adds some text at the end of the count...

    `find . -name "*.php" -exec chmod 755 {} \; -exec /bin/echo {} \; | wc -l | { read count; echo "Done. $count php file(s) processed."; }`

Comment: In this case, you could just add the `-print` option to the find, instead of executing a second command. Something like: `find . -name "*.php" -print -exec chmod 755 {} \; | wc -l`

Comment: @FelipeFG - You're probably right. I've never combined the `-exec` with the `-print`, but I guess there's no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: This solution assumes that the command to execute does not print outout of its own.

Answer (score 9):

You can chain multiple `-exec` commands with a single find command.  The syntax for that is:

```
find . -exec cmd1 \; -exec cmd2 \; -exec cmd3 \;
```

which in your case would look like this:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec chmod 755 {} \; -exec echo '+' \;
```

Although you have a few other options for this.  You can redirect output to a file:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec chmod 755 {} \; > logfile.txt
```

Or, you can use `tee`, which will allow you to write the output to a logfile, *and* still output to the screen.  I find this useful, as the continuously-streamed output to the screen lets me know that the command is still running (not crashed or hung), and I still have the log file to refer to later.

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec chmod 755 {} \; | tee logfile.txt
wc -l logfile.txt           // prints the lines in the file
grep -c '^+$' logfile.txt   // prints the lines containing a single '+'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec chmod 755 {} + -printf '.' | wc -c
```

If you use + instead of ";", find will try to process chmod 755 on many files in parallel.

You can perform additional commands after the first one, here, for example print a dot, and count the dots in the end.

Answer (score 0):

With the -exec option find will start a subprocess for each file found. You could speed this up by using xargs like `find . -name '*.php' | xargs chmod 755` - chmod is started only once.

Comment: Your second paragraph is incorrect. xargs knows how to limit long commands, that is a common usage for same.

Comment: Be careful with `xargs` if there are spaces, tabs, or NL in the file names. Also, `xargs` doesn't necessarily take the names of all the files. It fills up the command line buffer, executes the command, and then fetches the next group of files.

Comment: Linux' gnu-find has the option to handle multiple files in parallel as well, if terminated by a plus: `find . -name "*.php" -exec chmod 755 {} +`. You nearly never need xargs together with find.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) and [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml). Possibly:

```
find . -name "*.php" | pv --line-mode | xargs chmod 755
```

Note: this is only going to work if your *.php files do not have any spaces or other odd characters in the path or name.

Comment: Use `-print0` for find and `-0` for xargs, it'll solve all your space related issues

Comment: @Hasturkun not if you want to use `pv`. If you don't pipe the output from `find` with new lines, then you can't use the --line-mode switch for `pv`. And if you don't use that switch, then coming up with a way to tell `pv` how much data to expect will be a little more than tricky.

Comment: True, though a little bash trickery can probably solve this, eg. `find . -name "*.php" -print0 -fprint >(pv --line-mode) | xargs -0 chmod 755`