# Count and remove old files using Unix find

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I want to delete files in `$DIR_TO_CLEAN` older than `$DAYS_TO_SAVE` days. Easy:

```
find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -mtime +$DAYS_TO_SAVE -exec rm {} \;
```

I suppose we could add a `-type f` or a `-f` flag for `rm`, but I really would like to count the number of files getting deleted.

We could do this naively:

```
DELETE_COUNT=`find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -mtime +$DAYS_TO_SAVE | wc -l`
find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -mtime +$DAYS_TO_SAVE -exec rm {} \;
```

But this solution leaves a lot to be desired. Besides the command duplication, this snippet overestimates the count if `rm` failed to delete a file.

I'm decently comfortable with redirection, pipes (including named ones), subshells, `xargs`, `tee`, etc, but I am eager to learn new tricks. I would like a solution that works on both bash and ksh.

**How would you count the number of files deleted by `find`?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using find with -exec {}, is there a way to count the total?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719785/using-find-with-exec-is-there-a-way-to-count-the-total)

Comment: No, this isn't a duplicate. The other question does not ask or address what happens to the count when the `-exec`ed command fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use bash within find:

```
find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -mtime +$DAYS_TO_SAVE -exec bash -c 'printf "Total: %d\n" $#; rm "$@"' _ {} +
```

Of course this can call `bash -c …` more than once if the number of files found is larger than MAX_ARGS, and it also can overestimate the count if rm fails. But solving those problems gets messy:

```
find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -mtime +$DAYS_TO_SAVE -exec bash -c 'printf "count=0; for f; do rm "$f" && (( count++ )); done; printf "Total: %d\n" $count' _ {} +
```

This solution to avoid MAX_ARGS limits avoids find altogether. If you need it to be recursive, you'll have to use recursive globbing, which is only available in newer shells. (`globstar` is a bash 4 feature.)

```
shopt -s globstar
# Assume DAYS_TO_SAVE reformatted to how touch -m expects it. (Exercise for the reader.)
touch -m "$DAYS_TO_SAVE" referencefile
count=0
for file in "$DIR_TO_CLEAN/"**/*; do
    if [[ referencefile -nt "$file" ]]; then
        rm "$file" && (( count++ ))
    fi
done
printf 'Total: %d\n' "$count"
```

Here's an approach using find with printf (strictly compliant find doesn't have printf, but you can use printf as a standalone utility in that case).

```
find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -type -f -mtime "+$DAYS_TO_SAVE" -exec rm {} \; -printf '.' | wc -c
find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -type -f -mtime "+$DAYS_TO_SAVE" -exec rm {} \; -exec printf '.' \; | wc -c
```

Comment: I love a good one-liner, but I shall go with the loop, perhaps with the `find` piped to into it. Should be easiest for anyone after me to maintain, avoids MAX_ARGS issues, and allows easy access to the `rm` return code. Thank you!

Comment: @Prashant don't pipe find, that's dangerous: What if one of your filenames has newlines in it?

Comment: `find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -mtime +$DAYS_TO_SAVE | while read FILE; do rm "$FILE"; done` Quoting "$FILE" only handles spaces, but not newlines?

Comment: Ah, I tested and see your point about newlines now, kojiro. Thank you for the insight. A [link](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) I found for any readers later.

Answer (score 5):

I would avoid `-exec` and go for a piped solution:

```
find "$DIR_TO_CLEAN" -type f -mtime +$DAYS_TO_SAVE -print0 \
| awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '{ print } END { print NR }'  \
| xargs -0 rm
```

Using `awk` to count matches and pass them on to `rm`.

#### Update:

*kojiro* made me aware that the above solution does not count the success/fail rate of `rm`. As `awk` has issues with badly named files I think the following `bash` solution might be better:

```bash
find "${DIR_TO_CLEAN?}" -type f -mtime +${DAYS_TO_SAVE?} -print0 |
(
  success=0 fail=0
  while read -rd $'\0' file; do 
  if rm "$file" 2> /dev/null; then 
    (( success++ ))
  else
    (( fail++ ))
  fi
  done
  echo $success $fail
)
```

Comment: This answer would count files that `rm` failed to delete. Also, as an edge case, `xargs` is limited by MAX_ARGS or its `-n` option.

Comment: @kojiro: Yes there is no check that `rm` succeeds. `xargs` automatically calls `rm` the number of times needed, or do I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: It's a subtle point, but the difference between this question and the "count the files" question proposed as a dupe is that this one asks how to count only the ones that were successfully deleted.

Comment: Ah I see, hadn't noticed that. I've added a bash solution that should do it.

Comment: @Thor, I removed the tail, resulting in a 'pure' shell solution.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld: this will not work in `bash` as the `while` loop runs in its own sub-shell. Try this: `success=0; while [[ success < 10 ]]; do (( success++ )); done; echo $success`.

Comment: I ran the code, and got non-zero results for my counters.  What version of bash did you use? My BASH_VERSON is 4.1.5(1)-release

Comment: Heh not sure what went wrong when I tested it but I am unable to reproduce the behavior now. Your way is better, did a new rollback.

Comment: Thanks!  What you said was true for really_old_shells, like the original bourne. These days I try to be aware of the common feature set of bash and ksh93.