# Script to find and copy files

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a script that looks for a list of files and copies them to another directory:

```
for file in `cat ~/fileNames.txt`; do cp $(find $PWD -name $file) $TARGET_DIR; done
```

Printing out `$file` works as expected but find is not returning any output in the following script I use for debugging:

```
for file in `cat ~/fileNames.txt`; do echo $file; echo $(find $PWD -name $file); done
```

I know that the files are in one of the sub directories below $PWD

Update:

Using the -exec option only copies the last file in the list.

```
for file in `cat ~/fileNames.txt`; do find $PWD -name "$file" -exec cp -f {} $TARGET_DIR \;; done
```

Using while loop does not seem to be doing anything different:

```
cat ~/fileNames.txt | while read file; do echo $file; find $PWD -name "$file" -exec cp -f {} $TARGET_DIR \;; done
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you know the file name why are you doing the `find`

Comment: The files are not in the current directory but in one of the many sub directories.

Comment: Aha, well played, that is a good use of `find` here

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I updated the question.

Comment: `find` has an `-exec` option that it think could come in handy. check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719785/using-find-with-exec-is-there-a-way-to-count-the-total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Never do this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
for file in `cat ~/fileNames.txt`; do
```

It's subject to word splitting and pathname expansion. Instead you'll want to read your file with a `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    # stuff
done < ~/fileNames.txt
```

Then you can use `find` with its `-exec` action:

```
find . -name "$file" -exec cp {} "$target_dir" \;
```

So that finally:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    find . -name "$file" -exec cp {} "$target_dir" \;
done < ~/fileNames.txt
```

Comment: The format of the file is one file name per line, so the parsing is fine. Using the -exec option only copies the last file in the list. Check out the updated question.

Comment: @ventsyv No, the parsing with `cat` _is not fine_. It will break as soon as you have a space or a glob character. This is covered in [BashFAQ/001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: @ventsyv How can you tell that _only the last file in the list is copied_? do you have several times the same file name? do you have several files with the same name?

Comment: Changed to a while loop, nothing gets copied. All file names are distinct, nothing is repeated.

Comment: @ventsyv: can you provide a sample of your file `fileNames.txt`? Do you have any glob characters in there?

Comment: No globs, standard ascii names like MyClass.java and listDir.cc. One entry per line, no empty lines or funny characters.

Comment: @ventsyv do you have leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: No. The file was created on Windows, so I checked for weird characters, but I don't think there are any.

Comment: @ventsyv Use `set -x` to see what Bash is doing… without any more information, I can't really help…

Comment: There are some weird characters after all. I cat the file, then copy and pasted the output in a new file and everything seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
while read -r file; do
   find . -name "$file"
done < ~/fileNames.txt
```

And to copy files:

```
while read -r file; do
   find . -name "$file" -exec cp {} "$TARGET_DIR" \;
done < ~/fileNames.txt
```